# lftp mirror local directory to remote ftp server without deleting remote files which are missing locally

Tags: backup, lftp

I have the following command:

```
lftp -e 'mirror -R /local/backups /' -u username,password ftp://FTP_SERVER
```

this works fine, until I started cleaning the `/local/backups` folder. I'd like to upload new files to my `FTP_SERVER` without deleting those which don't exist locally anymore.

I've tried the additional flags:

```
--only-missing
--only-newer
```

but neither is working. Is it at all possible? I know rsync has such an option, but that doesn't work with FTP servers.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't look like mirror is the right thing. Possibly `--skip-noaccess` could work. Otherwise you might need to build an explicit file list rather than using `-R`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

lftp **mirror** command does not remove files by default, only if you add **-e** or **--delete** options.

To confirm that, use mirror **--dry-run** option.

Comment: LFTP | Version 4.8.3 appears to have no --dry-run option

Comment: it's a mirror option, use it like this: lftp -c "mirror --dry-run ..."